# How to use SetCC in Yii

Tags: php, email, yii

Hi I am trying to send an email using the code below, It works as expected until and unless I use setCC function. On using  `setCC` function mailer is not sending mail ( no errors). Could someone help with this code, thanks

```
use Yii;

class Email {       
    /**
     * @param unknown $template
     * @param unknown $to
     * @param unknown $subject
     * @param array $data
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static  function sendEmail($template, $to, $cc='my@email.com', $subject, $data = [], $proforma = false) {
        $mail =  Yii::$app->mailer
            ->compose($template, $data)
            ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'] => 'MyDomains.com'])
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setCc($cc)
            ->setSubject($subject);`
```

Comment: How do you call this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Third Parameter** of your function `sendEmail` i.e $cc must be an `email` but you are passing *"Payment ok"* in it a regular string. which is causing the error and you are not receiving email.